# C# Trying to make a guess the combo minigame

Tags: c#, random, int

Im trying to make a little game inside of my game that gets you to guess the numbers between 1-9 and gives you 20 guesses to do it. The first number works however I cannot get to 2, 3 and 4. One more thing is that I would like the random numbers to not change every time you guess. The last problem is that if you hit enter without entering anything it comes up with an error (0000005e   newobj Void System.FormatException:.ctor (String))

Im just making this game for a class in school and im pretty new to C#

Thanks in advance!

```
public static void safeCracking()
    {
        //Guess the numbers one at a time with a visual.

        if (safe.guesses == 20)
        {
            playerDeath();
        }

            //First number
            Random n1 = new Random ();
            int num1 = n1.Next (1, 10);

            //Second number
            Random n2 = new Random ();
            int num2 = n2.Next (1, 10);

            //Third number
            Random n3 = new Random ();
            int num3 = n3.Next (1, 10);

            //Fourth number
            Random n4 = new Random ();
            int num4 = n4.Next (1, 10);

                Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.Write("Guesses: ");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", safe.guesses);
                Console.WriteLine("");

                Console.WriteLine("     =================================    ");
                Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
                Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
                Console.WriteLine("     |   {0}   |   {1}   |   {2}   |   {3}   |    ", safe.cn1, safe.cn2, safe.cn3, safe.cn4);
                Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
                Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
                Console.WriteLine("     =================================    ");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Guess the first number of the combination.");
                Console.WriteLine("");

                string numg = Console.ReadLine();
                numberOf.puzzleGuess = numg;
                int numberG = Int32.Parse(numg);

                //Check number 4
            if (safe.cn3 < 0 && (numg == num4.ToString()))
                {

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Correct!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    safe.cn4 = numberG;
                    safe.safeLocked = false;
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Guesses: ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", safe.guesses);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    safeCracking();
                }

                //Check number 3
            else if (safe.cn2 < 0 && (numg == num3.ToString()))
                {

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Correct!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    safe.cn3 = numberG;
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.Write("Guesses: ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", safe.guesses);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    safeCracking();
                }

                //Check number 2
            else if (safe.cn1 < 0 && (numg == num2.ToString()))
                {

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Correct!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    safe.cn2 = numberG;
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.Write("Guesses: ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", safe.guesses);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    safeCracking();
                }

                //Check number 1
            else if (safe.cn1 >= 0 && (numg == num1.ToString()))
                {

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Correct!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    safe.cn1 = numberG;
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.Write("Guesses: ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", safe.guesses);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    safeCracking();
                }

                else {

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Incorrect!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    safe.guesses++;
                    safeCracking();

                }

        if (safe.safeLocked = false)
        {
            //Continue game here...
        }

    }
```

Comment: why using 4 random initializers? 1 is enough, you can always call `Next(1,10)` on it.

Comment: Okay that makes sense but how would I have it stay the same if you get it wrong?

Comment: I am guessing that you are calling this function in a loop? That's why it keeps generating new random variables every time. Instead you should make a `for-loop` inside this function to `ReadLine()`

Comment: You should wrap all the checking code in a for loop from 0 to 20. Inside the loop you `ReadLine()` and use TryParse (in order not to crash the program when empty number is entered. TryParse will return 0 if it could not parse the number correctly)

Comment: Is there a way that I could put the randoms in a class and call on them from there so they dont get changed becuase i dont really know how to use a for-loop @Everyone

Comment: I will try to divide your function into smaller set of functions that would make it readable.

Comment: Okay thank you sounds good. You dont have to do it all but enough so I can understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since I do not know what `safe` is nor what `numberOf` is I have tried my best with their absence to make it clear. I hope this helps you figure out what you need to do. You should call `safeChecking` only once and it will repeat the necessary actions inside of it:

```
public static void printScreen() {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Write("Guesses: ");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", safe.guesses);
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("     =================================    ");
        Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
        Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
        Console.WriteLine("     |   {0}   |   {1}   |   {2}   |   {3}   |    ", safe.cn1, safe.cn2, safe.cn3, safe.cn4);
        Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
        Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
        Console.WriteLine("     =================================    ");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Guess the first number of the combination.");
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void Checking(ref int safeCN, int numberG) {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Correct!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
        Console.ResetColor();
        safeCN = numberG;
        safe.safeLocked = false;
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Guesses: ");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", safe.guesses);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        safeCracking();
    }

    public static void safeCracking() {
        //First number
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num1 = rand.Next(1, 10);
        //Second number
        int num2 = rand.Next(1, 10);
        //Third number
        int num3 = rand.Next(1, 10);
        //Fourth number
        int num4 = rand.Next(1, 10);

        // this is the for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            // check here if exceeded maximum trials
            if (safe.guesses == 20) {
                playerDeath();
            }

            // print the screen in each loop iteration
            printScreen();

            string numg = "";
            int numberG = 0;
            try{
               numg = Console.ReadLine();
               numberG = Int.Parse(numg);
            } catch {
               numg = "";
               numberG = 0;
            }
            numberOf.puzzleGuess = numg;
            //Check number 4
            if (safe.cn3 < 0 && (numg == num4.ToString())) {
                Checking(ref safe.cn4, numberG);
            }

            //Check number 3
            else if (safe.cn2 < 0 && (numg == num3.ToString())) {
                Checking(ref safe.cn3, numberG);
            }

            //Check number 2
            else if (safe.cn1 < 0 && (numg == num2.ToString())) {
                Checking(ref safe.cn2, numberG);
            }

            //Check number 1
            else if (safe.cn1 >= 0 && (numg == num1.ToString())) {
                Checking(ref safe.cn1, numberG);
            } else {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Incorrect!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ReadLine();
                safe.guesses++;
                safeCracking();
            }
        }

        if (safe.safeLocked = false) {
            //Continue game here...
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks this is a real big help and I learned a thing or two :)

Comment: @Josh Glad I could help :)

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to bother you but im still having the issue where if you hit enter it comes up with an error. I have not a clue about why it would do that.